# Azure pricing calculator not updating estimates

Tags: azure, cloud, calculator

I am trying to price out various azure services and when I add them to the calculator and make changes the estimate does not update.

I have tried this in Edge, IE, Chrome, Firefox (normal browsing and Private) and I get the same results.

I also ran CCleaner and removed all of the files for each browser.

The calculator did work a few days ago.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. A solution that works for me is to open a new InPrivate window from the Edge browser.  (A new private window from Firefox did not solve the problem).

Perhaps the problem is related to cookies? I have not tested after deleting all cookies. @jake, when you used CCleaner, was it set to delete cookies or just cached data and files?

(For what it is worth, in the Firefox developer console I see several warnings  related to failed loading of JS scripts. I can't say if such a failure is the cause of the problem, but it looks like Microsoft needs to do better testing of the calculator page.)